# What license would be correct for an online version of a proprietary board Game?

Tags: open-source-software, gpl

For a student project we created on online version of "The Game" and now we have to decide which open source license (MIT License, GPL, Apache License, etc.) would be the most suitable for this code. We basically implemented the board game in code, to be able to play it online. Since the intellectual property of the game still resides with the original creator, we are not sure if we are even allowed to release the software under open source license on Github. We do not intend to run this as a commercial project. We are planning to include a disclaimer on the screen saying that "the associated logo and game assets are under copyright by the original creators".

Comment: You (or your supervising faculty member, if there is one) should probably talk to the legal department of the school at which you study.  I suspect that they'll tell you not to publish anything without written permission from the owners of the copyright and trademarks in "The Game."  Also, which ["The Game"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Game) did you implement?

Comment: Perhaps it's the one which you just lost.